# campo decimal tirando a virgula c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde,

fiz uma atribuição da seguinte forma:

```
dadosRedistribuicao.QUANTIDADE = (Decimal.Parse(txtDisponivel.Text) * Decimal.Parse(percentual)) + Decimal.Parse(distribuicao);
```

dadosRedistribuicao.QUANTIDADE é do tipo decimal, por isso estou convertendo o que vem do campo texto. 
A variavel percentual e distribuicao vem de uma grid e passo assim:

```
string distribuicao = gvMaterial.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
string percentual = gvMaterial.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
```

O valor do txtDisponivel é 113, o valor do percentual é 0.77 e o valor da distribuicao é 1. o resultado era pra ser 88,01 porem está vindo 8702, alguem pode me dizer o pq ?

desde já agradeço.

Comment: qual valor está na variável `gvMaterial.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text`  ? `0.77` ou `0,77` ?

Comment: 0,77 porem estou dando um replace com percentual = percentual.Replace(",", ".");

Comment: Provalvemente o `Parse` está sendo feito considerando "." (ponto) como separador de milhares. Deve funcionar se você informar `0,77` em vez de `0.77`. Ou, melhor, se você ajustar a conversão do texto para número decimal de acordo com um padrão. O resultado que você está obtendo é de 113 * 77 + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse Cálculo:

```
    string distribuicao = "1";
    string percentual = "0,77";
    string disponivel = "113";

    decimal quantidade = decimal.Parse(disponivel) * decimal.Parse(percentual) + decimal.Parse(distribuicao);
```

Resulta: `8702`

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OC90ma)

O Correto, seria esse:

```
    string distribuicao = "1";
    string percentual = "0.77";
    string disponivel = "113";

    decimal quantidade = decimal.Parse(disponivel) * decimal.Parse(percentual) + decimal.Parse(distribuicao);
```

Resultado: `88.01`

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UH4ZZI)

> A única diferença é o separador do percentual.

Comment: Muito obrigado, nem acredito que cometi esse erro bizarro kkkkk valeu deu certo